# NPE in context when selecting item in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm creating an app that has some tabs and each tab has a Fragment. One of the tabs display articles/news in a ListView, and I want to be able to tap in an article and then display the full story. However, when I tap in any item of the ListView, I get a NullPointerException. I checked the Logcat and I found that my context in the fragment is null, so every time my `onItemClick` method gets triggered, the context it receives is null. I've read numerous answers in here, no luck, I've also read blogs about adding some code like this

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context=getActivity();
}
```

but no luck either. This is my Fragment

```
public class DummyFragment extends Fragment{
    static ListView newsList;
            Context context=getActivity();
           ///some other declarations
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dummy, container,false);
   newsList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.newslist);
   setRetainInstance(true); 
   return view;
}

public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context=getActivity();
}

public void displayNews(final List<Item> news){
    itemAdapter=new ItemAdapter(context,(ArrayList<Item>) news);
    newsList.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowArticle.class);//here's where I get the NPE
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                item=news.get(position);
    });
}
```

}

Here's where I manage the Fragments I have in my app

```
class AdapterView extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
public static int NUM_ITEMS=3;
DummyFragment dummy=new DummyFragment();
//some other dummy fragments

public AdapterView(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch(i){
    case 0:
        return dummy;
    case 1:
        return anotherOne;
    case 2:
        return vandOther;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  NUM_ITEMS;
```

}
}

Here's my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private String tabs[]={"News",...};
ViewPager viewPager=null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
AdapterView adapterView;
DummyFragment dummy;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        public void onPageSelected(int position){
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterView(fragmentManager));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabs.length);
    adapterView=new AdapterView(getSupportFragmentManager());
    /*initialization of the action bar: color, icon & title.*/
    final android.app.ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar();
    //configuring the actionbar
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener=new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }   


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  

        }
    };
    /*Displaying Tabs for the app */
    for(int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++)
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

}

EDIT:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3350)
at com.example.test23.HomeActivity$1.onItemClick(HomeActivity.java:95)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: when I create the fragment, in the `onAttach()` method, the context is not null, so everything's fine. But when I tap in any option of the ListView, the context is null. The same happens with the activity.

If you need more code of information, please let me know. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: is DummyFragment an inner class??? and where did you put the field for context in DummyFragment ?

Comment: All my fragments are single classes, I have the context in the declaration field, but I commented it, let me post it for you

Comment: Can you post `HomeActivity.java`? and what is on its 95th line?

Comment: @Emmanuel the line 95 is the one that I posted where I get the NPE
`Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this.getActivity(), ShowArticle.class);`

Comment: Is that inside an `Activity`?

Comment: @Rosie That's not even a compilable line of code. `FragmentActivity` has no `getActivity()` method -- it *is* an `Activity`.

Comment: No, is in the Fragment, inside in the DummyFragment

Comment: Like @kcoppock, that code shouldn't compile.

Comment: the MainActivity is extending the Fragment activity,I'm trying to get the context in the fragment by declaring the context like this `Context context=getActivity();`, but I still don't understand why it isn't  a compilable line of code.

Comment: `MainActivity.this` is an instance of `Activity`. The `Activity` class has no method called `getActivity()` as it *is* an `Activity` and is not hosted in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the context from the `onAttach` of the fragment you can use the `getActivity()` instead of the context.

**problem:**

```
 public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context=getActivity();
}
```

you are getting the context from the fragment not from the parameter(`onAttach(Activity activity)`). thats why it is null.

**Solution:**

create an activity field:

```
      public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

and in the intent:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(activity , ShowArticle.class);//here's where I get the NPE
```

Comment: I changed it, but stills give me the NPE in the same line

Comment: @Rosie can you post all the error log or is that it?>

Comment: The `Activity` reference you get from `getActivity()`, and the parameter passed into `onAttach()`, are the same.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin `getActivity()` will *never* return null in `onAttach()`. I agree you should use the given parameter, but it's certainly not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Context being null. For me it was based in the implementation of the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Initially it looked like this:

```
public FingerprintPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return new FingerprintAcquireFragment();
    case 1:
        return new FingerprintResultListFragment();
    default:
        return new FingerprintAcquireFragment();
    }
}
```

After changing it to:

```
public FingerprintPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFingerprintAcquireFragment = new FingerprintAcquireFragment();
    mFingerprintResultListFragment = new FingerprintResultListFragment();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return mFingerprintAcquireFragment;
    case 1:
        return mFingerprintResultListFragment;
    default:
        return mFingerprintAcquireFragment;
    }
}
```

everything worked fine again.